# Count people overlapping, in a range of time in php

Tags: php

I have a series of div wich have a time example:

```
Mario  08:00 - 12:00
Luigi  08:15 - 12:15
Jhon   09:30 - 13:30
Carl   09:45 - 13:45
```

i want this output:

```
08:00 you have 1 person
08:30 you have 2 person
09:30 you have 3 person
12:30 you have 2 person
...
...
```

I do not have any idea to create a range. any help is appreciated.

I followed this reasoning: 
I tried to create a range, with a `range ()` from 08:00 to 17:00. then I put a condition `if ($ init == '$ range_var') {array_push (....)}`. once threw everything in the array I tried to regroup but I can not proceed ... I think it's the wrong range

Comment: I tried to create a range, with a `range ()` from 08:00 to 17:00. then I put a condition `if ($ init == '$ range_var') {array_push (....)}`. once threw everything in the array I tried to regroup but I can not proceed ... I think it's the wrong range

Comment: I think your range should be the time blocks you want to represent. i.e. 8:00, 8:30, 9:30 then you check to see if the range of time from the person is within that range array.

Comment: @VikingBlooded  you give an example

Comment: @napster3world see my answer below. I dont like it, but I know it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sloppy and I don't like it, and there is probably a better way but here's an example:

```
<?php

$time = array('08:00', '08:30', '09:30', '12:30', '13:30', '16:30');
$people = array(
    'Mario' => array(
        'start' => '08:00',
        'end'   => '12:00'
    ),
    'Luigi' => array(
        'start' => '08:15',
        'end'   => '12:15'
    ),
    'Jhon' => array(
        'start' => '09:30',
        'end'   => '13:30'
    ),
    'Carl' => array(
        'start' => '09:45',
        'end'   => '13:45'
    )
);

$countingArray = array();

foreach($time as $t){
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($people as  $key => $value){
        if(strtotime($value['start'])<= strtotime($t) && strtotime($value['end']) >= strtotime($t)){
             if(isset($countingArray[$t])){
                 $countingArray[$t] = $countingArray[$t]+1;
             }else {$countingArray[$t] = $counter +1;} 
        }
    }
}
foreach($countingArray as $key => $value){
    if($value > 1){
        $count = ' people <br />';
    }else{
        $count = ' person <br />';
    }
    echo $key . ' you have ' . $value . $count;
}
```